# Why does keras test generator only return batch size as the length in the shape of the array?

Tags: image-processing, keras, generator

Here is my test generator code:

```
test_generator=test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
                      dataframe=df_test,
                      directory=img_dir,
                      x_col="filename",
                      y_col="label",
                      batch_size=32,
                      seed=42,
                      shuffle=False,
                      class_mode="categorical",
                      target_size=(img_size,img_size))
```

Why does `batch_size` parameter still matter after you create the generator:

```
Found 229 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.
```

For example, the shape of the array after the generator is created is limited to 32 - the batch size:

```
x_test, y_test = test_generator.next()
```

here is the shape of `x_test`, I'm assuming this is the array with the actual image data:

```
>>> print(x_test.shape)
(32, 224, 224, 3)
```

This is the result when I compare it to the length of the predictions:

```
print(len(x_test))  #32
print(len(y_test))  #32
print(len(pred))    #229
```

Since the size of the `y_test` is vastly different than the predictions, I'm having difficulty doing any sort of comparisons. The `y_test` is directly related to the `test_generator` that has the batch size set at 32.

The test generator labels seems to have the right number of elements:

`test_generator.labels`

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0........
```

So why is the shape of `x_test` only 32?  I am obviously thinking incorrectly that it should be 229, since there are 229 samples, 229 labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe) state, what a generator returns is:

> A DataFrameIterator yielding tuples of (x, y) where x is a numpy array containing a batch of images with shape (batch_size, target_size, channels) and y is a numpy array of corresponding labels.

So, `test_generator` is a `DataFrameIterator`, which each time you call it, it will give you a batch of images with shape `(32, 224, 224, 3)`. Therefore you are thinking incorrectly that it should be 229, since there are 229 samples. Each time it will give you a batch of 32 images out of 229 sample.

Comment: Ah, OK thanks, I had seen that data type and wasn't sure exactly how it worked.  This helps me to understand what is going on.

Just a quick question, if I wanted to test the predictions, I can only test up to the limit of the batch size, 32.  I was hoping to test all of the samples in x_test against all of the predictions to see if I can get an "incorrect vs. correct" image table.   Thank you again for the clarification.

Comment: No. you are not limited to test only one batch of data. you can pass your generator to `model.predict` and it will give you a prediction of whole data, but since your generator batches data, it predicts batch by batch.